Redirect Std-output to a file and Err-output another file simultaneously
I want to get the std output and err out to be written in both files simultaneously by one command
echo $((1/0)) $((1+2)) > out.txt 2> err.txt

it print only the output to the shell not event to the err txt file
this command is only an example i want any command to write both file in the same time

Your redirection is correct as far as the echo .... command line goes ... The problem is that this command line isn't fully built or fully executed yet ... Arithmetic expansion happens first  and thus the error thrown is from $((2/0)) and not from your redirected command line ... You can run that whole command in a subshell  (...)and redirect the streams of that whole shell like (echo $((1/0)) $((1+2))) > out.txt 2> err.txt to collect output even of arithmetic expansion errors before the command is even fully built and executed.

... you could do exec &> >(tee -a err.log >> out.log) - see for example this recent answer Is there a way to use tee with the whole script from INSIDE the script?

Does this answer your question? Is there a way to use tee with the whole script from INSIDE the script?

ok I have found the answer the answer Parentheses is the solution
(echo $((1/0)) $((1+2))) > out.txt 2> err.txt

I think it execute the command and then redirect it but if there is an error it will push the error to the std output but in () brackets the command will execute and the result will be redirected to the file
